# Same views shared in two adapters

Tags: android, android-adapter

I would like to know is this possible in Android. I am using support library v4.
Problem I am having is that I have to show same custom views in two activities using two adapters, one adapter is supporting the view pager and the other is supporting grid. Basically there is a grid with images that you can view and then when you click on element it should open another Activity where you can view same images in a view pager. I tried just returning same views in fragment onCreateView method but get child already have a parent which I would expect, after removing view first using

```
((ViewGroup) myImageView.getParent()).removeView(myImageView);
```

I get java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: removeView(View) is not supported in AdapterView exception which I didn't expected to happen. Know I am stuck because I don't want to create new views but use existing in both adapters. 
My question is:
Could this showing of same view be done or am I on the totally wrong track and should implement this "Adapter link" some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could this showing of same view be done or am I on the totally wrong
>   track and should implement this "Adapter link" some other way?

There is no way to share views between two activities and you wouldn't want to do that anyway. Even if you used a single activity with fragments you shouldn't share views of an adapter as it could lead you to more problems.

The proper way to do what you want is to recreate the data in the two places you want the same data and this should be easy if you use an adapter. You'll basically need to use the same layout for the `ViewPager`'s pages in the normal adapter used for the `GridView`.

> I get java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: removeView(View) is not
>   supported in AdapterView exception which I didn't expected to happen.

A child of `AdapterView` manages its children through the adapter and the methods like `addView()` or `removeView()` are not implemented for them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This does point me in the right direction and I am going to test it out right now. Could you just please be more specific on "The proper way to do what you want is to recreate the data in the two places you want the same data and this should be easy if you use an adapter. You'll basically need to use the same layout for the ViewPager's pages in the normal adapter used for the GridView." The problem here could be that my custom objects contain both their data and view for example class has String imageUrl and ImageView FullImage.

Comment: @PSIXO Your custom object **shouldn't** contain the `ImageView` as it doesn't represent the model. You should make the model class contain only the data and leave the `ImageView` to the adapter to build. Then, like I already said, use the same layout in the adapter for the `ViewPager` and the adapter for the `GridView`.

Comment: I tried many things but in the end implemented something similar to what you suggested so thank you for your help. Also a child of AdapterView manages its children through the adapter and the methods like addView() or removeView() are not implemented for them. is a crucial information for me since I didn't know that. For these you get the right answer. I just don't understand the part about " use the same layout in the adapter for the ViewPager and the adapter for the GridView" so if you could just give me some more info on that it would be helpfull. Also,how do you link positions in adapters?

Comment: @PSIXO What you don't understand? Do you know how to build adapters for a `ViewPager` and a `GridView`? The position are already linked if you use the same list of data.

Comment: I was confused a little bit by "same layout" words but now get that you are referring to instantiating or inflating same view types so I was doing that all along. I still don't get how are they linked when using same list, because each adapter has its own getItem(position) and positions are not the same. I am currently passing selected element position in grid to second activity and selecting that element in view pager but how can I do it other way around: Change current element in grid from view pager on other activity?

Comment: @PSIXO Using the same list means the adapters will both have the same size. `getItem()`(instantiateItem for `ViewPager`'s adapter) using the `position` will point to the same item of data. Doing the selection is exactly the same, yous pass the current item in the `ViewPager` and use it to `setSelection()` on the `GridView`.

Comment: Thank you for more info. I ended up doing things like this actually  using setSelection() so they both start from the same position. Also this app is a little bit more difficult in this aspect since there is no single gridview but multiple grids in views pager but I solved this by multiplying positions accordingly.